# How to set setImageResource, I have URIs of the gallery images of my phone

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I have all the URIs of my phone images from Gallery as:

```
for(String item: items) {
    Log.d("Images", item);
}
```

its output are:

```
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150425_131643.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_213547.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_213646.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_221519.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_221530.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_221544.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_221628.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222055.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222533_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222541_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222552_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222637_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150426_222643_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150429_205140_HDR.jpg
07-04 17:30:22.633  11140-11140/com.example.android.HomeWork2 D/Images﹕ /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150429_205148_HDR.jpg
```

I want to populate these in gridview. We can set static image present in Drawable as:

```
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

where:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
     R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher
};
```

My gridview is:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

I am wondering how I can set images dynamically, as I donn't know how many images are there in the gallery and their URIs until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an Adapter that will populate the grids for you. Wait till you have the information about the images, then populate the adapter appropriately. A good tutorial showing how to use gridviews and populate them with images+text can be found [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html).